# Handling exceptions WPF Application with a WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-client

I have a WCF Service that talks to the DB. All the operations go through the service. 
What is the best way to return an exception to the client(in this case WPF application).

Lets say I have GetCustomer in the service which returns a list of customers. But this had an exception. How should I return this exception to the client?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft recommends implementing [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) for WCF exceptions

> To explicitly control the behavior of the application when an
>   exception is thrown, **implement the IErrorHandler interface and add it
>   to the ErrorHandlers property. IErrorHandler enables you to explicitly
>   control the SOAP fault generated, decide whether to send it back to
>   the client, and perform associated tasks, such as logging.** Error
>   handlers are called in the order in which they were added to the
>   ErrorHandlers property.
>
> *Implement the ProvideFault method to control the fault message that is
>   returned to the client.*
>
> *Implement the HandleError method to ensure error-related behaviors,
>   including error logging, assuring a fail fast, shutting down the
>   application, and so on.*

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFErrorHandling.aspx) is better sample than MSDN

```
IMyService proxy = ...;    //Get proxy from somewhere
try {
    proxy.MyMethod();
}
catch (CommunicationException) { ... }
catch (TimeoutException) { ... }
catch (FaultException<MyApplicationFault> myFault) {
    MyApplicationFault detail = myFault.Detail;
    //Do something with the actual fault
}
catch (FaultException otherFault) { ... }
```

Comment: how does one return this exception/fault to the client in your example?

Comment: you do not return exception from service rather throw it from service  throw new FaultException<MyApplicationFault>(fault); and client will catch with above code.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to have information about any potential exceptions be part of your service contract.  So, in your example, GetCustomer returns your list of customers. but it also returns a, potentially empty, set of data about any exceptions that occurred.  This is a good idea because not every consumer of your service is going to be a .NET application, to depend on sending .NET errors is not wise.